# Can't get the temperature to change from Celsius to Fahrenheit in my local weather app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

1. User Story: I can see the weather in my current location.
2. User Story: I can see a different icon or background image (e.g. snowy mountain, hot desert) depending on the weather.
3. User Story: I can push a button to toggle between Fahrenheit and Celsius.

These are the user stories for the website. I have managed to complete 1 and 2 but I am completely stuck on 3, I have a good idea of how I would manage to do this but I can't manage to make it work with various methods(not just the one in my code) but I think I may of coded this badly but it is the only way I know because I am new. Someone suggested to me to use an if but it doesn't work as it would only be able to change the text on document load and not continuously. This is the [example](http://codepen.io/FreeCodeCamp/full/bELRjV). Any advice on a better way about this would be greatly appreciated and sorry for the long post.

Html:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Weather!</h1>
    <hr />
  </div>
  <div class="search">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="searchBtn">Search</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 checkbox" id="degrees">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="" id="fCheck">View in °F</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 content" id="temp">
      <h2></h2>
      <h3></h3>
      <h4></h4>
      <p></p>
      <img src="" alt="weather icon" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 info">
      <h2 id="humidity"></h2>
      <h2 id="windspeed"></h2>
      <br>
      <h2 id="sunrise"></h2>
      <h2 id="sunset"></h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  background-color: #3f3f3f;
}
.main{
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto auto auto;
  width: 75%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #8E9EBC;
  padding: 10px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.main h1 h2 h3 h4{
  margin: 0;
}

.main img {
  width: 100px;
}
.title hr {
  border-width: 2px;
}

#degrees h4 {
  text-align: left;
}
#searchBtn {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var api = "secretAPIKey";

  $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json", function(json)  {
    var userCity;
    userCity = JSON.stringify(json.city);
    userCity = userCity.replace(/\"/g,"");    
    makeElementsFromCity(userCity);
  });
  var celsius;
  var name;
  var faren;
function makeElementsFromCity(userCity) {
    $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + userCity + "&units=metric&appid=" + api, function(json) {
        name = JSON.stringify(json.name + ", " + json.sys.country);
        celsius = JSON.stringify(json.main.temp);
        faren = celsius * 9 / 5 + 32;
        var icon = JSON.stringify(json.weather[0].icon);
        var type = JSON.stringify(json.weather[0].main);
        var humidity = JSON.stringify(json.main.humidity)
        var windS = JSON.stringify(json.wind.speed);
        var sunR = JSON.stringify(json.sys.sunrise);
        var sunS = JSON.stringify(json.sys.sunset);
        icon = icon.replace(/\"/g,"");
        type = type.replace(/\"/g,"");
        celsius = Math.round(celsius);
        faren = Math.round(faren);
        //get sunset and sunrise unix into time
      function formatSunR(date) {
        var date = new Date(date*1000);
        var hours = date.getHours();
        var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
        var seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds();
        var formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2);
        return formattedTime;
      };
        //update h2 with city, country and temperature and testing to see what weather.icon is but comes back as undefined
        //updates h3 with the type of weather & city is placeholder for testing the city variable
        $("#temp h3").text(type);
        //display image of weather type from https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions
        $("#temp img").attr("src", "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + icon + ".png");
        $(".info #humidity").text("Humidity: " + humidity + "%");
        $(".info #windspeed").text("Wind Speed: " + windS + " MPH");
        $(".info #sunrise").text("Sunrise: " + formatSunR(sunR));
        $(".info #sunset").text("Sunset: " + formatSunR(sunS));

      if($("#fCheck").is(":checked")) {
        $("#temp h2").text("The temperature in " + name + " is " + faren + "°F");
      } else {
        $("#temp h2").text("The temperature in " + name + " is " + celsius + "°C");
        console.log(faren);
      }
      });

    };


});
```

Comment: Why do you call `JSON.stringify`? Just leave that out.

Comment: Just FYI: most if not all of the things you `JSON.stringify` are strings and numbers, not objects. `JSON.stringify` is used to turn an object into a string in JSON, it is not needed to extract info from it.

Comment: Im learning from freecodecamp.com and I just saw that they used it and presumed I always needed it

Comment: Don't just copy code blindly. Try to understand WHY they use it when they do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this HTML

```
<a href="#" id="toggle">temp</a>
```

with this JS and adapt it to your situation.

```
        var temp = 25;
        var celsius = temp;
        var fahr = (1.8 * temp + 32);
        var switch_ = new Boolean(false);

        $("#toggle").on("click", function() {
            switch_ = !switch_;
            var temp = switch_ == true ? celsius + " °C" : fahr + " °F";
            $(this).text(temp);
        });
```